# Single stepping until exit from function gdb

Tags: c, multithreading, debugging, parallel-processing, gdb

I have a project which I am working on and it has multiple files and I use make to compile the project. Here is the makefile

```
CC =  /opt/gcc-4.7-cilkplus/bin/gcc
CFLAGS = -ggdb3 -Wall
COMPLILEFLAGS = `mysql_config --include` -I/opt/gcc-4.7-cilkplus/include/
LINKERINFO = `mysql_config --cflags --libs` -lrt -lm -lz
CILKFLAGS = -lcilkrts

# To be provided at the commandline
DIR = './bloom'
MODE = '2'
FILENAME = 'database.info'

exec: main.o mysql-client.o databaseConnection-common.o murmurhash3.o bloom-filter.o md5.o auxilary-functions.o
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o exec main.o mysql-client.o databaseConnection-common.o murmurhash3.o bloom-filter.o \
    md5.o auxilary-functions.c $(LINKERINFO) $(CILKFLAGS)

main.o: main.c mysql-client.h databaseConnection-common.h bloom-filter.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(COMPLILEFLAGS) -c main.c $(CILKFLAGS)

bloom-filter.o: bloom-filter.c bloom-filter.h murmurhash3.h auxilary-functions.h 
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(COMPLILEFLAGS) -c bloom-filter.c

murmurhash3.o: murmurhash3.c murmurhash3.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c murmurhash3.c

md5.o: md5.c md5.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c md5.c

mysql-client.o: mysql-client.c mysql-client.h databaseConnection-common.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(COMPLILEFLAGS) -c mysql-client.c

databaseConnection-common.o: databaseConnection-common.c databaseConnection-common.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(COMPLILEFLAGS) -c databaseConnection-common.c

auxilary-functions.o: auxilary-functions.h auxilary-functions.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c auxilary-functions.c

run:
    ./exec $(MODE) $(FILENAME) $(DIR)
```

I set `breakpoint` at some location and then do `next` form there but I get

`Single stepping until exit from function bf_dup_eleminate_read,
which has no line number information.`

`bf_dup_eleminate_read` is a function in `bloom-filter.c`. I cannot understand why this is happening even if `bloom-filter.c` is compiled with proper options

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don not see anywhere the `-g` flag. It informs compiler to emit debugging info, so you need to add it to compilation line, if you wish gdb to show you line numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Try to update your gdb. It might be that your `gcc` version was too new. I got the same problem and fixed it after updated my gdb.

Answer (score 0):

Well its 2021 so things are a bit different now. Typicly I find the `-ggdb` flag more useful. It isn't only more verbose, it also seems to be less error prone (but thats my opinion). You also need to make sure that you add the `-ggdb` flag to all the object files as well. To give some sort of reference, and a more solid way to get your project going if its not debugging as expected. Here is a snippet from a project I just built and debugged sucessfully in `VSCode v1.62.1`. It was compiled w/ **`GNU C++ Compiler g++ 10.3`**, debugged with **`GNU Debugger gdb v9.2`**, and built using the make command via **`GNU Make 4.2.1`**

```
# Here is an example from my current project that I debug on vscode
TARGET = A10
ALL = fraction.o main.o
GCC = g++
FLAGS = -Wall -c

${TARGET}: fraction.o main.o
    ${GCC} -Wall -ggdb ${ALL} -o ${TARGET}

main.o: main.cpp fraction.h
    ${GCC} -Wall -ggdb -c main.cpp

fraction.o: fraction.cpp fraction.h
    ${GCC} -Wall -ggdb -c fraction.cpp fraction.h
```